# how to undo a commit pull

Tags: mercurial, commit, undo, pull

I faced today my first mercurial problem. I was in my repo, I modified a file and I did a

```
hg commit
hg pull
```

followed by 
    hg update 
    hg rollback

to repair what I've done, (but actually I didn't push anything)
The problem is that when I did the pull (that I should do before the commit, the head changed and so hg heads looks like :

```
- Modif from yesterday
- My modif
- Modif from last week
```

and now I see that someone also did another modification (via the http interface). What should I do to repair my local repo, (if possible modifying my summary) and push it after the 2 others modifications.

Thanks a lot. Quiet confusing, was easier on my "one-man" repo..

Comment: have you read http://hginit.com/? i think this very case is made an example there.

Comment: What @mizipzor said, if you find this confusing you should really take some time to read a tutorial. Here are some more: http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/basic/#divergent-lines-of-development, http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial, http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html

Comment: hginit already, I'll read the others. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local repo doesn't need "repairing". This is a very standard case that you will see often if you use Mercurial a lot.

The issue is ***multiple heads***.

You can either merge your heads, assuming your working directory is your version and there is only the other head:

`hg merge`

This will result in a merge changeset (same as if you were merging across branches).

Or you can enable the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) to re-base your version onto the tip of the branch (the other head):

`hg rebase --source<YourVersionNumber> --dest<TipVersionNumber>`

This will **not** result in a merge changeset, and will simply transplant your changes on top of the changeset you specify as if they were born of that changeset all along (hence rebase or "new"basing).

Multiple heads is a funny sort of inner-branch branching... you can continue checking stuff in against your own head and change between heads using `hg update`. We block multiple heads per branch on our server, so our push would fail. I'd advise keeping multiple heads local as they are less clear-cut than branches.

I tend to work with Mercurial in one of two ways:

1. If the work is large in scale I will branch it off and follow Continuous Integration practices (constantly merging the main branch into my own etc). I then re-merge back into main when I am happy with the end result.
2. If the work is small in scale I will simply work against main branch and "merge" heads every so often. I say "merge" as I usually use rebase. Re-basing works great if the changes are simple and conflicts are unlikely.

My hard and fast rule: if I can't use rebase I put it on a branch born of main.

Comment: I can't merge because of multiples head. So, I tried to active rebase in my extensions, but unfortunately, rebase doesn't seem to be activated on the repo.

Comment: You need to enable it in the config, it's deployed with Mercurial but not activated. Merging should work fine even with multiple heads - are you sure you don't have uncommitted changes?

Comment: Ok I fixed it without rebase. Thanks for the help !